# How to install Twisted 16.2.0 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, twisted

I am trying to install Twisted 16.2.0 but it throw below error.I used **pip3 install Twisted==16.2.0**  command to install twisted.

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Twisted==16.2.0 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Twisted==16.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

pip3 install Twisted

will install latest updated version of Twisted 17.1.0

[Reference:-](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads) https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads

Comment: if u want old versions of Twisted 16.2.0  download it from here and install it         https://twistedmatrix.com/Releases/Twisted/